# How to make equal padding in row with Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, padding

I want to create equal padding with all div under the .slideshow div. The problem is the last div right padding.

Now looks like this:

[image]

I want this, just with equal padding / space between divs and equal img heights:

[image]

The code:

HTML:

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="product-container">
                <div class="slideshow">
                    <p>Test message, Test message</p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                    <img src="http://www.pacinno.eu/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/placeholder-Copy-4.png" alt="s">                    
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                    <img src="http://www.pacinno.eu/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/placeholder-Copy-4.png" alt="s">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                    <img src="http://www.pacinno.eu/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/placeholder-Copy-4.png" alt="s">                    
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                    <img src="http://www.pacinno.eu/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/placeholder-Copy-4.png" alt="s">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');

.product-container{
    padding: 0px 9%;
}
.slideshow{
    background-color: #efeff1;
  border: 1px solid #c5c5c7;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.product-container img{
    width:100%;
}
.col-lg-3{
    padding-right:12px;
    padding-left:0px;
}
```

Fiddle:
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/12059/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap all your image containing divs in additional `.row`:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        <img src="http://www.pacinno.eu/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/placeholder-Copy-4.png" alt="s">                    
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        <img src="http://www.pacinno.eu/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/placeholder-Copy-4.png" alt="s">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        <img src="http://www.pacinno.eu/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/placeholder-Copy-4.png" alt="s">                    
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        <img src="http://www.pacinno.eu/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/placeholder-Copy-4.png" alt="s">
    </div>
</div>
```

And remove unnecessary styling:

```
.col-lg-3{
    padding-right:12px;
    padding-left:0px;
}
```

Also, you don't need to repeat responsive classes for all devices:

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3"></div>
```

Can be written:

```
<div class="col-sm-3"></div>
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/12060/)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're trying to acheive?

```css
.product-container {
    padding: 0 2px 6px 2px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.slideshow {
    background-color: #efeff1;
    border: 1px solid #c5c5c7;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.product-container img {
    width: 100%;
}
.product-container .pads {
    padding: 0px 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="product-container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="slideshow">
          <p>Test message, Test message</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 pads">
          <img src="http://www.pacinno.eu/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/placeholder-Copy-4.png" alt="s">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 pads">
          <img src="http://www.pacinno.eu/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/placeholder-Copy-4.png" alt="s">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 pads">
          <img src="http://www.pacinno.eu/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/placeholder-Copy-4.png" alt="s">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 pads">
          <img src="http://www.pacinno.eu/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/placeholder-Copy-4.png" alt="s">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the last-child selector. "Bla" is a class I added to the divs in question

```
.bla:last-child{
   padding-right:0px ;

}
```

Had some issues with the height but used `display: flex;` to deal with that.

This wont work well in older browsers

http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/12065/

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
remove

.col-lg-3{
 padding-left:12px;
 padding-right:0px;
}

add

.product-container .col-lg-3
{
padding-left:0px;
padding-right:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the right padding is removed it will have the result you are looking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/0rm0h547/light/

http://jsfiddle.net/0rm0h547/show/

**css**

```
.continuous {
    padding-right: 0px;
}
```

**html**

```
..
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 continuous">
                    <img src="http://www.pacinno.eu/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/placeholder-Copy-4.png" alt="s">                    
                </div>
..
```

Add an extra css class that removes `padding-right`.

Answer (score 0):

You can give padding-right:0px; and you will get wat you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/12070/

```
.col-lg-3{
    padding-right:0px;
    padding-left:0px;
}
```